# How to reduce javascript for video js?

Tags: javascript, video.js

I'm trying to implement video-js on my company website, and it works beautifully. BUT the page speed load time as reported by google page speed insights is abysmal.

The culpret seems to be the large amount of included javascript at:
https://vjs.zencdn.net/7.6.5/video.js

Even if I minify it and host on my server.

It's a pretty simple implementation, and I was wondering if anyone has come across this and found a way to speed things up, perhaps by editing out code that is not necessary for a simple implementation.

Thanks in avance!

Comment: I assume you've done what the video.js documentation says to do if you want to self host? (https://docs.videojs.com/docs/guides/setup.html)

Comment: Are you sure the bottleneck is not the videos which the player is loading?

Comment: The question of why are you using videos js?  Why don't you just create a simple custom player in which u have control over it?  I will understand using videojs for recording and other advanced features,  If you desperate needs videos then try to find minimized js in cdn or slim,

Comment: Thanks guys. Mike: Not sure exactly what you mean. The videos (mp4, webm) are on my website, I link to the cdn css and js. I followed the video js examples. slynagh: Tested that already. Vanilla html5 video gives me A's for page load speed. user9954622: I'm now looking into that. I'd prefer ofc to not reinvent things. Looking for good examples including ones with big centered play buttons.